# How to remove from vector of pairs the value item from pair that is a class in c++?

Tags: c++, std-pair, erase-remove-idiom

i am trying to remove all Orders that have old pizza than 3 days :

i have this vector of pairs :

```
 std::vector<std::pair<Client,Order>> x;
    x.push_back(std::make_pair(Client(2,"Anca"),Order(3,1)));
    x.push_back(std::make_pair(Client(16,"Maria"),Order(1,3)));
    x.push_back(std::make_pair(Client(29,"Alex"),Order(10,5)));
```

and this class Order:

```
class Order{
private:
    int amountPizza;
    int pizzaAge;
public:
int getPizzaAge(){
        return pizzaAge;
    }
```

and i did something like this :

```
auto it=x.begin();
   while(it!=x.end()){
        if((it->second).getPizzaAge()>3){
            x.erase(std::remove(x.begin(),x.end(),it->second),x.end());
        }
        it++;
    }
```

and is not working.

```
Errors:

error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::pair<Client, Order>' and 'const Order')
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
 'std::pair<Client, Order>' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>'
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
```

Comment: yes,you are right,i modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using extra `while` loop is wrong. The moment you erase first element, `end()` iterator is invalidated. Fortunately, `std::remove` (and `std::remove_if`) can handle any number of elements in a single call.

The second issue is that `std::remove` can only be used for removing exactly same elements (compared with `operator ==`). However, using `std::remove_if` you can provide a comparison function that is more flexible.

Your code should look like this:

```
auto newEnd = std::remove_if(x.begin(), x.end(), [](const auto& p) {
    return p.second.getPizzaAge() > 3;
});
x.erase(newEnd, x.end());
```

Comment: I have tried this and it's working but it's removing all pair,i want to remove only the Order (Order(10,5)) ,but Client to remain (Client(29,"Alex")).It is possible to do this ?

Comment: @loveProgram You can't remove part of a pair, since that wouldn't be a pair any more. If you want the order to be optional, use `std::optional<Order>`.

Comment: It's not. Type of `x` is `std::vector<std::pair<Client,Order>>` , which means for every `Client` there is always an `Order`. If you want clients without orders, you need to change the type of `x` accordingly. If there is at most one order, you can use `std::vector<std::pair<Client,std::optional<Order>>>` or if there may be more than one Order you may consider `std::vector<std::pair<Client,std::vector<Order>>>` (or a similar `std::map`, but there is no `std::remove_if` for `std::map`, you will have to write a loop)